# Issue with overlaying dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(".add_option").click(function () {
    alert("!");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 250,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    "Create": function () {
        $("#choose_info").append('<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns options">/
        <input id="checkbox' + checkbox_no + '" type="checkbox"></input><label id="check' + check_no + '">' + $("#option_name").val() + '</label>/
                </div>');
        checkbox_no++;
        check_no++;
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
},
close: function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
});
});
```

and here is my html:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Option">
    <label for="option_name">Option Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="option_name" id="option_name">
</div>

<button class="tiny radius add_option">Add Option</button>
```

Somehow the div `dialog-form` doesn't get overlayed i.e the dialog box doesn't open.

Comment: What is `$(".add_option")` supposed to select ? It is nowhere in your HTML.

Comment: oh sorry updated my question

Comment: please provide all details correctly next time..

Comment: I've tried to put that into a jsFiddle, but it didn't work - it's probably a syntax error somewhere in your `$().dialog()` call. Please create one and post the link here so we can at least have something to work on. (You're probably going to solve your problem by yourself by the way).

Comment: @DarkKnight do you see any error in your browser console?

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/G7xke/111/

Comment: @Nikhil no but my javascript code doesnt work from there onwards

Comment: @DarkKnight I have formatted your code and removed extra `})` at bottom and its working...see http://jsfiddle.net/G7xke/114/

Comment: ok...m glad issue is resolved..:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just formatted code and removed extra `})` at end..and everything works fine..

Check this demo...http://jsfiddle.net/G7xke/114/